# Cocos2d Create a CCGLView in a NSWindowController custom View

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, nswindowcontroller

I want to be able to have Cocos2d contain in it's own NSWindowController such that the AppDelegate will be able to manage several different instances of Cocos2d running that the same time in different windows.

Each time I load Cocos2d in the NSWindowController subclass, I get a blank view in the OpenGl View.

[image: Resulting OpenGL View subclassed to CCGLView]

Why is it not rendering the scene properly?

**Cocos2dWindowController.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface Cocos2dWindowController : NSWindowController <CCDirectorDelegate>{

    CCGLView    *glView_;

}

@property (strong) IBOutlet CCGLView    *glView;

@end
```

**Cocos2dWindowController.mm**

```
#import "Cocos2dWindowController.h"
#import "PuzzleWorld.h"

@interface Cocos2dWindowController ()

@end

@implementation Cocos2dWindowController

@synthesize glView=glView_;

- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{
    self = [super initWithWindow:window];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.


    }

    return self;
}


- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];

    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.

    //Check to see if the view is empty prior to launching
    CCDirectorMac *director = (CCDirectorMac*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    // enable FPS and SPF
    [director setDisplayStats:YES];

    // connect the OpenGL view with the director
    [director setView:glView_];

    director.delegate = self;

    // EXPERIMENTAL stuff.
    // 'Effects' don't work correctly when autoscale is turned on.
    // Use kCCDirectorResize_NoScale if you don't want auto-scaling.

    [director setResizeMode:kCCDirectorResize_AutoScale];

    // Enable "moving" mouse event. Default no.
    [self.window setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:NO];

    // Center main window
    [self.window center];

    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    [scene addChild:[PuzzleWorld node]];


    // Run whatever scene we'd like to run here.
    if(director.runningScene)
        [director replaceScene:scene];
    else
        [director runWithScene:scene];


}

//Override the close action to kill off Cocos2d and OpenGl
- (void)close{

    [super close];

    //Check to see if the view is empty prior to launching
    CCDirectorMac *director = (CCDirectorMac*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    [director setDelegate:nil];
    [director end];

}

@end
```

[image: Xib Configuration]

This is occurring on Cocos2d 2.0 with Xcode Version 4.6 (4H127)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you why your screen is white. If you base it off of the Cocos2D Mac template, check the MainWindow.xib. The Cocos2D view spans the entire window, so just resize it and work with that.

What I **can** tell you is that your goal of **running multiple cocos2d views is futile**: cocos2d only supports a single view.

Support for multiple views has been on the roadmap for years, and it doesn't look like it'll come anytime soon. It's a non-trivial change as well, given how reliant cocos2d is on Singletons for many core classes (Director, ActionManager, Scheduler, Caches, ...).

Comment: Instead of multiple windows, how about just one for the interim? I need to be able to launch a few different Cocos2d scenes from the same app delegate. The app delegate will be tracking test data in the scene from the test participant with it's own window. when the test is over the Scene will close and return to the main window until launching another scene.  I know I could do the same by replacing the scene with Cocos2d, but this would be much easier considering that data gathering portion of the project.